# User without create table permission when using babelfish as a target endpoint in AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, babelfish

I'm trying to migrate some data from SQL Server to AWS Aurora (Postgres) by using the babelfish capability. It was recently added as a target in the AWS DMS service. However, the connection test fails with the following message:

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: User does not have to create table permission  Endpoint initialization failed.
```

What I did was follow the [babelfish target documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54nma.png) that suggests those steps for permissions setup (connected to the 1433 port).

1. Create a login and password to use when connecting to the server.
2. Create the virtual database for your Babelfish cluster.
3. Create the T-SQL user for your target database.
4. For each table in your Babelfish database, GRANT permissions to the tables.

```
CREATE LOGIN dms_user WITH PASSWORD = 'experiments';
GO

CREATE DATABASE database_test;
GO

USE database_test
GO
CREATE USER dms_user FOR LOGIN dms_user
GO
```

After that, I apply the SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE grants for each table in `database_test` database. This is the setup of my babelfish endpoint:

[image]

Am I missing something? Why my user has no `create table` permission after completing step 3?

Comment: Same problem here. @joão-neto did you find any workaround?

Comment: @bfcamara hi! unfortunately, I ended up migrating my databases manually.